# Pejorative Word or phrase for when tourist undergoing Government procedures for visa formalities is experience based

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions, pejorative-language

Pejorative Word or phrase for when a Government does not have its procedure in place for citizen or migrants or tourist for simple formalities like passport renewal or visa renewal or visa application or visa extension, etc. Every thing is personal experience based of individual citizen or migrants or the tourist. Requirement changes every time you go to the ministry offices.

Although Sri Lankan is a touristic country, but the Government over there has not placed  a standard procedure for visa extension. As in which all documents are required to be produced, etc. It all ___________ (visitor's individual experience based)

Answer (score 1):

You could go with "discretionary". That means that the official who processes the application is free to decide on whether they will grant an extension, on a case-by-case basis.

*Although Sri Lanka has a thriving tourism industry, the country's government has yet to define a formal procedure for visa extension. Requirements are decided on a case-by-case basis, at the discretion of the official who processes the request.*

Comment: Nice answer, it could be strengthened with a link or a dictionary citation. Welcome to ELU.